# How can I not strip html in sphinx attributes?

Tags: sphinx, exist-db

I have an exist-db database with a couple of (large) TEI xml files which I want to index/search. For indexing, I have an `xmlpipe2` command calling a *sphinx-out.xql* url served by the exist db. Along with the actual texts snippets (paragraphs, headings, notes etc.), this provides a couple of attributes that I later want to use when presenting search results. One of them is a *crumbtrail* field that contains html (more precisely, it contains a series of `<a>` hyperlinks).

As I want to be able to offer sentence and paragraph operators in searching, I have set `index_sp = 1` and since this in turn requires html stripping, I also have `html_strip = 1`. But this seems to strip the html also from my attributes, which I want to retain...

Here is what *sphinx.out.xql* and then the *xmlpipe2 command* give:

```
<sphinx:docset>
<sphinx:document id="77">
  <sphinx_docid>77</sphinx_docid>
  <sphinx_work>W0013</sphinx_work>
  <sphinx_author>Vitoria, Francisco de</sphinx_author>
  <sphinx_title>Relectiones</sphinx_title>
  <sphinx_year>1557</sphinx_year>
  <sphinx_crumbtrail>
    <span class="crumbtrail">
      <a href="/exist/apps/salamanca/work.html?wid=W0013#Vol02">Vol. 2</a>
      <span class="tokenizer"> &gt; </span>
      <a href="/exist/apps/salamanca/work.html?wid=W0013#Vol02Lect01">De augmento charitatis</a>
    </span>
  </sphinx_crumbtrail>
  <sphinx_description>
    <p xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0" xml:id="p_l3w_pml_y4">
      [SNIP]
    </p>
  </sphinx_description>
</sphinx:document>
 .
 .
 .
</sphinx:docset>
```

And here is what a mysql query to sphinx gives:

```
mysql> select sphinx_docid, sphinx_work, sphinx_crumbtrail from salamanca_base;
+------+--------+--------------+-------------+---------------------------------+
| id   | weight | sphinx_docid | sphinx_work | sphinx_crumbtrail               |
+------+--------+--------------+-------------+---------------------------------+
  .
  .
  .
|   77 |      1 |           77 | W0013       | Vol. 2 > De augmento charitatis |
+------+--------+--------------+-------------+---------------------------------+
20 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now I wonder if there is any way for me to disable html stripping for attributes?

**Can anyone at least confirm that it is possible to store html in sphinx attributes?**

Thanks for any insight

Comment: Are you sure you need index_sp? It's NOT needed for **phrase** search.

Comment: I know eXist-db very well, but this question seems to be specifically about Sphinx, or have I missed something?

Comment: @adamretter, yes I think getting sphinx to do what I want is the more obvious approach. I just wanted to put everything on the table, perhaps I should be approaching the issue from a different angle. E.g. one of the approaches I tried was base64-encoding the crumbtrail html so that sphinx does not even look inside. But it turned out (or so I think) that eXist's util:base64-encode encodes also only the actual text/string content, stripping the html no matter what, so I was no further.

Comment: @barryhunter, I'm sorry, I was confused. I meant I wanted to offer Sentence and paragraph operators. Tbh, I don't (yet) know if I am going to really *need* it, but it sure sounds nice. Will keep you updated on that as well.

Comment: I tried with ``html_index_attrs = span=class;a=href`` and even with ``index_sp = 0`` and ``html_strip = 0``, but still did not get html in attributes. Am I doing something wrong? Did anyone ever successfully use html in a sphinx attribute?

Comment: are you completely reindexing when changing settings?

Comment: ``time sudo -u sphinxsearch indexer --all --rotate`` should do that, shouldn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use `html_index_attrs` so that spans and a's are not removed?

html_index_attrs = span=class,a=href

Comment: this does not help. Then again, nothing does, not even disabling ``html_strip`` so I started wondering if I am doing anything wrong...